# Is GUI programming for internet browser made more easy than for desktop?

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, desktop-application

I'm not a great programmer, to me it's just a hobby. I am more interested in desktop programming than web programming. When it comes to making a GUI however, it strikes me how difficult it seems to make a fully customised GUI with effects etc. for desktops, while websites are full of different designs and special effects. Of course, there is a need of consistency between applications on desktop, which somehow isn't needed on the Internet. Yet it seems desktop programmers are bound to using pre-sets of GUI kits (Gtk, Qt, Wx etc.), and overcoming the former looks like a huge amount of work.

So that's a subjective statement of mine. And that's a very naughty thing to do on a Stack Exchange website. But is this statement somehow justifiable or founded on some (technical) truth?

If not, could you provide with some information? NB: I work on Linux only.

Comment: This is subjective. You can't get a direct answer for this. I think web designing is far more easier than designing desktop GUI.

Comment: What's the point of this question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to find out whether my impression is correct, or whether I have only been working with wrong material so far. If my impression is incorrect, then perhaps I hope to be guided to find a more convenient way to GUI programming for desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, desktop GUI design is easier simply due to the abundance of such aforementioned tools. In my experience, it's easier to implement a complex GUI as a desktop application, than the equivalent GUI on a web browser. In the latter case you need to take browsers, screen size, sessions, security and many more factors into account.

Comment: Thank Sean, do you refer to any particular GUI programming library?

Comment: @Benjamin I haven't used an extensive array of libraries, just standard Swing and WinForms programs. However I've never ran into problems which were too complex - now that I'm using ASP.NET, I can see quite a difference. If you're looking to start out, Swing is quite easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for answering in spite of the negative feedback around this question.